# Changing Navigation Bar color while using @android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar

Tags: android, android-theme, android-launcher

Actually I am using

> @android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar

in my android launcher app. But the problem is when I am changing

> navigation bar color

for lollipop and above devices, it's not changing. I tried pro-grammatically as well as from styles.xml.

If I am using appcompat theme, then it's working. But I don't wanna use appcompat theme for my launcher app. So what is the reason behind it and give me solution as well.

Comment: you can't chage the color of NavigationBar. Or maybe you are talking about Status bar or notification Bar?

Comment: nope, i'm talking about navigation bar color. Its changing while I am using appcompat theme but not with Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar..

Comment: Can you show some screenshots?